# Change image on click with HTML area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image with multiple image maps. If one link/area is clicked I want the image to change into another image. So for example if `ID="02"` is clicked I wamt the image source to change to `02.png` and so on...

The markup I have for the `area` shapes are:

```
<img src="01.jpg" usemap="#Map" alt="">


    <map name="Map">
        <area shape="rect"  id="02" coords="7,6,191,375" href="#" alt="">
    </map>
```

How can I use jquery/javascript to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("area").click(function() {
      var areaId = $(this).attr("id");
      $("img").attr("src", "" + areaId + ".png");
   });

});
```

Edit: Working fiddle here: jsfiddle.net/940yj9vr/1

Comment: Didn't work for me. I changed the code a bit to simplify the question. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Do you have an example maybe?

Comment: Hey, here's a working fiddle with that exact jQuery. https://jsfiddle.net/940yj9vr/1/ (Of course change the "li" click event to "area" in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
      $('area').on('click', function() {
        if(this.id<10){
          url = (this.id*1);
          url ='0'+ url;
        }else{
          url = (this.id*1); 
        }
       // url=this.id*1;
        console.log(url)
          $("img").attr("src", url + ".png");
      });
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: i see change in your post for click on 01 to 02...updated as posted ..now displays same id image on click

Comment: i have created codepen with spans which works same for area tag as well
http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/BzLWmK